# Show custom multi-select attribute values as images

Tags: image, multiselect-attribute

I am trying to display a custom multiselect attribute as images on the frontend if they have been selected by the store admin.

So far I have been able to get the values "as text" on the frontend but I am not sure how I can go about associating each value with an image...

Here is what I have so far

```
 <?php
   $multiSelectArray = $this->getProduct ()->getAttributeText('suitable_for');
   $lastItem = end ($multiSelectArray);
   foreach ($multiSelectArray as $multiSelectItem) {
   echo $multiSelectItem;
   if ($multiSelectItem != $lastItem) echo ", ";
     }
 ?>
```

The above code will show the values of the multiselect but I am stuck on how to associate the values with an image instead of text.

I anyone can assist I'd be very grateful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
 <?php
   $multiSelectArray = $this->getProduct ()->getAttributeText('suitable_for');
   $lastItem = end ($multiSelectArray);
   foreach ($multiSelectArray as $multiSelectItem) :?>
   <img src="/media/img/<?php echo $multiSelectItem ?>"></img>
   <?php endforeach;
 ?>
```

and store your images in /media/img/[item].[ext], the same value as the text stored.

Comment: Nice approach.  May be file extension (jpeg or similar) needed as well as basic file name validation.

Comment: Fantastic!!! Thankyou so much, I really appreciate your help...

Comment: good one!!!!!!!