# How to show an image as "Option Label" in admin form multi-select field in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

How to  show an image as "Option Label" in admin  form multi-select field in Magento 2

[image]

Multi-Select Field

```
$fieldset->addField(
            'flag',
            'multiselect',
            [
                'name'        => 'flag',
                'label'    => __('Name'),
                'required'     => true,
                'values'   =>  $this->appliedFlags->toOptionArray(),
                'note'     => 'Set flags to column'
            ]
        );
```

options

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

class Flagoptions implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface
{
    const IMAGE_HEIGHT = '25';
    const IMAGE_STYLE = 'display: block;';

    public function __construct(
        
         \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ) {
       
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $height =  self::IMAGE_HEIGHT;
        $style =  self::IMAGE_STYLE;
        $options =array();
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $collection = $objectManager->create('Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Orderflag\Collection')
            ->addFieldToSelect(array('flag_id','name', 'image_icon'));
        $options[] = array( 'label' => 'NONE', 'value' => '-1'  );
        if( $collection->getSize() ){
             foreach ( $collection  as $flag) {
                 $srcImage = $this->_storeManager->getStore()
                        ->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) .$flag->getData('image_icon');
                 $ext = pathinfo($srcImage, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                 if($ext != '')
                 {
                    $image ="<img src='" . $srcImage . "' height='" . $height . "'/>";
                    $name = $flag->getData('name');

                    $label = $image.ucfirst($name);
                        
                }        
                 $options[] = array( 
                 'label' => $label,
                 'value' => $flag->getData('flag_id')
                );
             }
         }
      
       
        return $options;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried - htmlspecialchars_decode() ?

Comment: I  posted a tried one on above

Comment: Try this one - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/30718/show-custom-multi-select-attribute-values-as-images

Comment: you should use dropdown instead of multiselect field to display image. Maybe image can not display inside multiselect field.

Comment: i changed a  dropdown instead of multiselect field, image not shown https://prnt.sc/uznh8a

Comment: You might need to convert that text to html.

Comment: Where i have t o convert a text to HTML in an above code

Answer (score 0):

I think NO way to do if you using default magento/ui template. Because your code is using magento/ui component `ui/form/element/multiselect`. In template have this code `optionsText: 'label'`. So I think you should create custom template for this element.